# Angular ng-repeat not reflecting update to list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive that injects a dynamic template on ng-repeat. I'm wanting to add to that list, which, I can, but for some reason none of the items I add to the list are reflected in the view. I know it's close, but I seem to be missing something.

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bullrout/Dpv9r/) with the code.

```
   $scope.
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your fiddle is not working !

Comment: Fix your fiddle please

Comment: I've tried everything to get that fiddle working. I'm not sure what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but injecting a template like that does not sound like a good idea. You can just use HTML and let AngularJS do the repeating/hiding/etc for you.

Also, every time you declare `ng-controller` in your HTML, a new instance of the controller is created. These instances *do not* share a common `$scope` and is probably not what you want either.

To fix AngularJS unable to inject the application module, I moved the binding of `myApp` to the body tag:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

which I read about [here](http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/).

I forked your fiddle to a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/42rpB/2/

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering my question. I did try to add the ng-app="myApp" to the fiddle but I see that you've removed the directive as well. Very nice.